# how to position icon just after h2 tag using :after pseudo even though 100% width

Tags: css

Was wondering if anyone know how I can position the triangle icon directly after the text of my `h2` tag, at the moment I use :after and float this to the right but because the `h2` is `display: block` this triangle is positioned way to the right. Since I have a border-bottom that needs to stretch the `100%` I cant use `display: inline-block` to get my result. Wondering if I can achieve this without having to add in empty spans etc

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bCwv/

HTML:

```
<h2 class="definition-heading">Tools for Internet Users</h2>
```

CSS:

```
    h1, .carousel-caption, h2, h3, h4 {
    font-family:"Proxima Nova Semi Bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #454545;
    font-size: 16px;
}
h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.definition-heading:after {
    content:'';
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 7px solid #e15646;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    margin-left: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `inline-block` on your generated content, it should do exactly what you're after. See [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/znJ5q/), CSS changes:

```
.definition-heading:after {
   display: inline-block; /* add this */
   /* float: right;
   top: 7px; remove these */
}
```

Which gives:

[image: Screenshot using inline-block]

Answer (score 4):

@CherryFlavourPez has given the best answer and I would also like to suggest you to style your triangle icon `vertical-align: middle;` so that your heading and triangle will look fine.

**Edit**

You can also display your triangle icon without using above method, an easier method is here:

```
<h1>heading text here<span>►</span></h1>
```

Style your span now. (triangle icon is copied from character map)